# How to remove stuff from a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of structs:

```
list<structure>;
```

But I want to remove the specific stuff by ID.

Example: item with ID 55.

So how I can reomve a stuff from list?

I have an ID in the struct as `public string stuffID;`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove everything with an ID of 55:

```
List<Structure> list;
list.RemoveAll(structure => structure.ID == 55);
```

Comment: Is there perhaps something like RemoveOne so the whole list doesn't have to be traversed?

Answer (score 0):

`list = list.Where(item => item.id != 55).ToList();`

Comment: This won't work as you can't assign `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`.

Comment: then don't declare list as a List<T>

Comment: You'd need to add .ToList(), but it's still inefficient because it rebuilds an entirely new list. .Remove() is the best choice.

Comment: @tster I have updated your answer a little bit so it will work. Probably you meant that just forgotten the ToList() :)

Comment: @Cylon Cat, mutating the existing list might not matter, especially since this approach can be optimized by a linq provider.

Comment: @tster, .Where() iterates over an IEnumerable, returns an IEnumerable that meets the predicate condition. It doesn't alter antyhing.  As a general rule, attempting to alter an IEnumerable during iteration results in an exception, which is why List.Remove() is a method on the List collection, rather than an extension method on IEumerable.